# Using python and R in Jupyter notebook at the same time

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python and R code with jupyter notebook at the same time. Specifically, I want to use pandas to deal with the data, pass the DataFrame object to R kernal, and then use ggplot2 to visualize it.

However, as long as I pass the pandas DataFrame object to the R kernal, and use ggplot() to make plots,the jupyter notebook will always give a warning as following:

> C:\Study\Anaconda3-5.2.0\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.4-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py:191: FutureWarning: from_items is deprecated. Please use DataFrame.from_dict(dict(items), ...) instead. DataFrame.from_dict(OrderedDict(items)) may be used to preserve the key order.
>     res = PandasDataFrame.from_items(items)

My code is very simple, showing as the following:

`%load_ext rpy2.ipython`

`%R library(ggplot2)`

```
# data_train is a pandas DataFrame object
%%R -i data_train 
ggplot(data = data_train,aes(x = factor(Survived))) + geom_bar(fill = "#539bf3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it directly in python using [python ggplot library](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy)

Not exactly what you are asking but in case you overlook it